# Where is function definition of kotlin plus operator?

Tags: kotlin, intrinsics

I was just looking into the source code of Primitives.kt file in kotlin source to see the function code for 'plus' operator.

```
/** Adds the other value to this value. */
public operator fun plus(other: Int): Int
```

Can someone help me guide where is the code for this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions in `Primitives.kt` are implemented as compiler intrinsics. It means that when the compiler encounters such function invocation, it replaces that with some predefined sequence of lower level code or a call to another function.

For example in Kotlin/JVM, the function call `Int.plus(Int): Int` in this code

```
fun test(x: Int, y: Int) {
    x.plus(y)
}
```

is replaced with the bytecode sequence something like this:

```
    ILOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    IADD
```

And an example when an intrinsic function call is replaced with another function call:

```
fun test(x: Int, y: Int) {
    x.compareTo(y)
}
```

is compiled to:

```
    ILOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.compare (II)I
```

Here the static function `Instrincs.compare(Int, Int)` is called instead of the member function `Int.compareTo(Int)`.

Comment: Thanks @llya for giving me a great hint to search further.